# How to specify multiple role and recipe in bootstrap command in the run_list

Tags: chef-infra

When I try to specify multiple roles in the `run_list` of `knife bootstrap` command, it fails with following error

> Unable to create Chef::RunList::RunListItem from String:"role[A],role[B]"

How can I specify multiple roles/recipe or a combination of role/recipe in knife bootstrap command ?

Comment: that looks good to me. Make sure they are valid roles.  I regularly use 'role[something],recipe[some::recipe]'

Comment: I agree with that. What's your command line?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using wrapper cookbooks to define roles for a node instance of using chef's role feature.  You achieve the same end, and you also can write tests around your roles.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the following:

```
knife bootstrap HOSTNAME --run-list 'role[A],role[B]'
```